# Can't compare a key to another key in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I am iterating through an array with multiple keys in order to print the information of the authors(full code below), using *foreach*:

```
foreach($data as $authors) {
foreach($authors as $id){
   foreach($id as $key){
       if($key !== $key['id'])
       echo $key . '-';
   }

}
```

}

What i am trying to do here is: if there is a key 'id', don't echo it. Only echo Name, e-mail and date of birth.

The whole code:

```
 'authors' => [
     301 => [
         'id' => 301,
         'name' => 'William Shakespeare',
         'email' => 'william_shakespeare@example.com',
         'birthYear' => 1799,
     ],
     10 => [
         'id' => 10,
         'name' => 'Jack London',
         'email' => 'jack_london@example.com',
         'birthYear' => 1809,
     ],
     17 => [
         'id' => 17,
         'name' => 'Mikhail Lermontov',
         'email' => 'mikhail_lermontov@example.com',
         'birthYear' => 1814,
     ],
 ],

];



echo '=== Authors ===<br>';

foreach($data as $authors) {
 foreach($authors as $id){
    foreach($id as $key){
        if($key !== $key['id'])
        echo $key;
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up key and value in the innermost loop.

```
foreach ($data as $authors) {
  foreach ($authors as $author) {
    foreach ($author as $key => $value) {
      if ($key !== 'id') {
        echo $value . "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note 1: I renamed $id to $author, because that is what it is: an array of the author's details.

Note 2: If you shorten this line:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

to:

```
foreach ($array as $xxxx)
```

xxxx will carry the $value part, not the $key part, so it is:

```
foreach ($array as $value)   // foreach ($array as $key) does not work
```